# How to get Point.X at a Point.Y on a FlattenPathGeometry - WPF

Tags: wpf, path, geometry, pathgeometry

I have a "FlattenedPathGeometry" and I want to be able to get a specific point.X from the path based on a specific Point.Y

Basically I just need the X value at any given Y.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

GetFlattenedPathGeometry gives you back a polygonal so basically you have to consider loop all the points and calculating the minimum distance to your point.
If you can make any assumption on the Geometry shape or your point, you can speed up the search.

For example if the path is very long, you can speed up by intersecting the shape with a circle/square centered in your point. This limit the number of points of the shape to test but be careful that the intersection method is very expensive. You'll have to measure the performances with a stopwatch to understand what's better in your case.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now and it's just not very efficient, but I suppose if .NET exposed a method to do it, they would just use a similar approach anyway.  Best thing to do is make my lookup as efficient as possible.